# Creating directories with OS module

Tags: python, list, directory, nested-loops

**Hi there I'm trying to create a small tool that will create child directory's within the Root directory**

> Root Dir(python) And child Dir(DS, WEB, Flask, Learn) stuff like that

At starting I have done it statically Here is the Code

```
import os

web = "Web"
Ds = "Data-structures"
Learn = "Learn"
tools = "Tools"

list1 = []
var = int(input("Enter number of Dir:- "))
for x in range(0, var):
    Lang = input("Enter Lang:- ")
    list.append(Lang)


for i in list1:
    os.system(
        f'mkdir {i} && cd {i} && mkdir {web} && mkdir {Ds} && mkdir {Learn} && mkdir {tools}')
```

Then I decided to do it dynamically By using two lists just like before but thing's don't go well Here is the code

```
import os

A = int(input("Enter number of dirs to be in A Specific languge(Ex:1 or 2):- "))
list1 = []
for x in range(0, A):
    B = input("Enter the Dir name(Ex:- DS, Web..etc):- ")
    list.append(B)
print(list)


C = int(input("Enter number of languages to be In the Dir(Ex:1 or 2):- "))
list2 = []
for x in range(0, C):
    D = input("Enter languges Name(Ex:- python,php,Golang):- ")
    list2.append(D)


for i, j in zip(list2, list1):
    os.system(f'mkdir {i} && cd {i} && mkdir {j} && mkdir {j}')
#tried all combination that I know
#for i in range(0,lis1):
#    for j in list2:
#        os.system(f'mkdir {list2} && cd {list2} && {os.mkdir(list1[i])}')
```

So I do Some try on it by using nested for loop or while loop but I didn't get an answer for what I did
at the second code, I won't be able to give `for k in range(0, A):` if I give it's throwing me Error
`A subdirectory or file py already exists.` And it is obvious to Get the Error like I'm recreating the same content, again and again, using for loop

**What I want is to create Root:-Python child's:-Web, DS..etc**

> You don't want to use the same code if you know other ways Please Do
> let me Know

Please, anyone, Help me

Comment: don't use `os.system` use `os.mkdir` and `os.makedirs'

Comment: plus zip isn't going to _combine_ directories, you'll be better off with a double loop

Comment: I do use it but the thing is I want to it in Root Dir once iteration is completed it's again checking the same thing I tried every possibility I know so far the last hope is to get an answer out You guys

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name: this is a built-in function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To prompt the user, you can create a small function which ask for the user to enter values in order.

For example:

```py
def ask_values(prompt, input_msg):
    choices = []
    print(f"{prompt} (press <ENTER> when finished)")
    while True:
        choice = input(input_msg)
        if choice:
            choices.append(choice)
        else:
            return choices
```

This function will loop indefinitely until the user press `<ENTER>`, and then return the values.

You can then use this function twice: for the directories and for the languages:

```py
directories = ask_values(
    "Enter the directories",
    "Enter the directory name (ex.: DS, Web, etc.): "
)
print("=> directories:", directories)
print()

languages = ask_values(
    "Enter the languages",
    "Enter the language name (ex.: python, php, go, etc.): "
)
print("=> languages:", languages)
print()
```

Then, you need to loop over the directories and the languages to create the tree structure.
Don't forget to specify the full path of the root directory in a global variable (for instance):

*NOTE*: in this demonstration, I choose the current working directory: "."

Solution 1: using `os` module:

```py
import os

# Root directory of you directory tree
root_dir = os.path.abspath(".")

print("Creating directories...")
for dir_name in directories:
    for lang in languages:
        path = os.path.join(root_dir, dir_name, lang)
        try:
            os.makedirs(path)
        except FileExistsError:
            pass
print("Done.")
```

Solution 2: using `pathlib` module

```py
import pathlib

# Root directory of you directory tree
root_dir = pathlib.Path(".").absolute()

print("Creating directories...")
for dir_name in directories:
    for lang in languages:
        path = root_dir.joinpath(dir_name, lang)
        path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
print("Done.")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate the Work it's working Perfectly, Thanks To You I'm literally beating My head to the laptop for 5 hours!